# angular2 with webpack, module routing get system not found error

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing

I am now following Angualr Modules guide, but unlike the tutorial, I am using webpack as packaging solution. Everything is fine until I add the heroes module. For the default contact module, it is working no problem, but when I add heroes module, I got this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

I check a lot, such as modifying tscofig and set module to commonjs, it is useless

I think the different between contact module and hero module is:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'contact', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'crisis', loadChildren: 'app/crisis/crisis.module#CrisisModule' },
  { path: 'heroes', loadChildren: 'app/hero/hero.module#HeroModule' }
];
```

So the heroes module is lazy loading, unlike the contact module.

Has anyone met the error when you are using webpack instead of System to package your angular2 project?

Thanks

Frank

Comment: See how your heros module is build. It looks like your heros module is build using systemjs and that is why its searching for Systemjs.

Comment: how is that possible? Whole project is built with webpack, and hero is only a feature module inside the same project, I followed exactly the guide in ng2

Comment: can you give a plunker?

Comment: System is not defined --> it says its looking for system object and failing incase not getting it

Comment: I checked a lot, webpack for lazy loading in ng2, no working sample yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have followed the angular2 [webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) and [ngmodule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) guides what you need to do is:

`npm install --save-dev angular2-router-loader`

and add it to your typescript loaders in webpack config (in the webpack guide it's `config/webpack.common.js`):

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loaders: [
        'awesome-typescript-loader',
        'angular2-template-loader',
        'angular2-router-loader'
      ]
    },
    ...
```

and in your routing module make the paths relative to the module that loads them:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'contact', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'crisis', loadChildren: './crisis/crisis.module#CrisisModule' },
  { path: 'heroes', loadChildren: './hero/hero.module#HeroModule' }
];
```

to read more:
https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular2-router-loader
https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/angular-2-lazy-loading-with-webpack-d25fe71c29c1#.qnct3euh2